# Java8 - Functional Interface, Lambda and Method Reference

Tags: generics, lambda, java-8, method-reference, functional-interface

I have the following code

```
   public class FunctionalInterfaceTest {

  @FunctionalInterface
  public interface FunctionThatThrows<T, R> {
    R apply(T t) throws Exception;
  }

  public void perform() {
    try {
      unchecked((String x) -> Integer.parseInt(x)).apply("abc");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Encountered exception" + e.getMessage());
    }
  }

  public void perform1() {
    try {
      unchecked(<fill-in-here-using-method-reference>);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Encountered Exception" + e.getMessage());
    }
  }

  public <T, R> Function<T, R> unchecked(FunctionThatThrows<T, R> f) {
    return (a) -> {
      try {
        return f.apply(a);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    };
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    FunctionalInterfaceTest test = new FunctionalInterfaceTest();
    test.perform();
    test.perform1();
  }
}
```

I want to use Method Reference in the perform1 method to get similar result as in the perform method. I tried using a method reference like Integer::parseInt in perform1 but it doesnt work. How do I do the same with a method reference and why is the method reference giving an error?

Comment: Did you try `unchecked((FunctionThatThrows<String, Integer>) Integer::parseInt).apply("abc")`? and that didn't work which way?

Comment: @Naman That works. Why is the explicit typecast necessary?

Comment: how many `parseInt` are there that can potentially match your `Integer::parseInt`? When you cast, you explicitly say to the compiler _which_ `parseInt` to use

Comment: I thought its quite explicit that we are using parseInt from the java.lang.Integer. Why would that be ambiguous?

Comment: I don't know why the compiler doesn't pick up the right method, but is this a problem with a practical relevance? I mean, in real life you would use the result, like `Function<String,Integer> f = unchecked(Integer::parseInt);`...

Answer (score 1):

> How do I do the same with a method reference and why is the method reference giving an error?

You can't, unless there is an explicit type present. Since the `unchecked` method uses generic parameter `FunctionThatThrows<T, R>` the compiler doesn't know what these generic types `T` and `R` are. The following will not compile:

```
unchecked(s -> Integer.parseInt(s));    // doesn't compile
```

The compiler thinks `s` is an  `Object` which is not compatible with [`Integer.parseInt(String s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) method. That's why the it is ambiguous.

The point is, there must be explicitly stated the type of the generic parameter. There are three ways to define the type and keep generic solution.

1. As you have already done, specify that `s` is `String` using downcasting.

   ```
   unchecked((String x) -> Integer.parseInt(x))                 // no method reference
   ```
2. Use an explicit casting of the passed lambda expression. This solution is the first one that IntelliJ Idea offers to me. Now it is clear for the compiler input and output for the passed function is `String` and `Integer` respectively. Note this structure is what [`Integer.parseInt(String s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) requires`:

   ```
   unchecked((FunctionThatThrows<String, Integer>) Integer::parseInt); // with method reference
   ```
3. Explicitly, define a required return type:

   ```
   Function<String, Integer> f = unchecked((FunctionThatThrows<String, Integer>) Integer::parseInt);
   ```

   .. the redundant casting should be omitted and it gives a more clear result:

   ```
   Function<String, Integer> f = unchecked(Integer::parseInt);  // with method reference
   ```

   <sup>(Note [@Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) also brought this one in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61711373/java8-functional-interface-lambda-and-method-reference#comment109163307_61711373))</sup>